# How to add a div element in Viewer

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs, resium

the question is how to add a div element in Viewer.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5MjN.jpg)

the code is below.

cesium.js

```
import { Viewer, KmlDataSource } from "resium";
import { useState } from "react";
import styles from "../styles/Cesium.module.css";

const kml1 = ('./electric.kml');
const kml2 = ('./electric2.kml');

export default function Cesium() {
  const [showKml, setShowKml] = useState(false);
  const [showLabel, setShowLabel] = useState(false);

  const handleToggleKml = () => {
    setShowKml((prevShowKml) => !prevShowKml);
  };

  const handleToggleLabel = () => {
    setShowLabel((prevShowLabel) => !prevShowLabel);
  };


  return (
    <>
      <Viewer full>
        <KmlDataSource
          data={kml1}
          onLoad={(dataSource) => {
            console.log(dataSource);
          }}
          show={showKml}
        />
        <KmlDataSource
          data={kml2}
          onLoad={(dataSource) => {
            console.log(dataSource);
          }}
          show={showKml}
        />
        <div className={styles.buttonWrapper}>
          <button onClick={handleToggleLabel} className={styles.button}>
            button
          </button>
          {showLabel && (
            <label className={styles.label}>
              <input
                className={styles.input}
                type="checkbox"
                checked={showKml}
                onChange={handleToggleKml}
              />
              list
            </label>
          )}
        </div>
      </Viewer>
    </>
  )
}
```

index.js

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const Cesium = dynamic(
  () => import('../components/Cesium'),
  { ssr: false }
)

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="cesium/Widgets/widgets.css" />
      </Head>
      <Cesium />
    </>
  )
}
```

I want to add the div into the direct viewer.

Do I have to edit the library of resium or cesium?

I lost way to do that.  Does anybody help me.

I tried that adding div into viewer, but that did not work.

Comment: cesium.js path is src\components\Cesium.js
index.js path is src\pages\index.js
actually the cesium(resium) library is in the public(next.js)

Comment: I edited the css, then I fixed the issue. Could I delete this post?